# Get the value out of subscribe() Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tested different solution such as adding map or switchMap but I'm lost, I still can't get the data out of the subscribe of the Service function.

I have the service function :

```ts
getAllExperiments (): Observable<Experiment[]> {
   return  this.http.get<Experiment[]>(this.urlEndPoint)
     .pipe(
       catchError(this.handleError<Experiment[]>('getExperiments', []))
     );

   }
```

and the call in the `ngOnInit`:

```ts
async ngOnInit() {
      await this.experimentService.getAllExperiments()
      .subscribe( response => {
        this.expTable = response
        this.expId = this.expTable.length;
        console.log(this.expTable, this.expId) //appears after the other console.log but with the values
      })
      console.log(this.expId) //appears first and undefined

      await this.experimentService.getExperiment(this.expId)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.experiment = response
      });

      await this.compareService.getScore(this.expId)
      .then(response => {
        this.expScore = response;
      })

    }

  }
```

And obviously the function `getExperiment` with the ID doesn't work as well.

I know it should be able to work with a `toPromise` but I don't see how to use it here.

Comment: Move the calls that need `expId` *inside* the subscription callback. Or convert the observables to promises, rather than subscribing to them, if you want to `await` them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3):

1) ngOnInit is not async so remove `await` from file.

2) if you want to connet more request you should use `forkJoin` ([example](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)).

3) If you need data from first request use `switchMap` ([exapmle](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html))

```
this.service.methodA(paramA).pipe(
switchMap((resA)=>this.service.methodB(resA.paramB))
).subscribe((resB)=> {...});
```